# Porque não consigo exibir a imagem selecionada abaixo no meu browser?

Tags: html

```
<figure id="centro-distribuicao">
    <img scr="img/centro-distribuicao.png">
    <figcaption>Centro de distribuição da Mirror Fashion</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Cara só com esse pedaço de código não tem como te responder! Coloque o HTML inteiro e o CSS também. Edite a sua resposta e coloque o código

Comment: Se a imagem com o nome `centro-distribuicao.png` está na pasta `img` que está dentro da mesma pasta que está com o arquivo html era para ser exibida corretamente. Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/Getting_started_with_the_web/lidando_com_arquivos)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Infelizmente por descuido havia um erro de sintaxe que eu não havia percebido! Mas obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reparei que sua tag está escrita scr:

O correto é src:
[image]

Comment: Isso ai.... está escrito SCR ao inves de SRC.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Esse é meu primeiro código e acredite, já fiz de tudo pra que essa imagem fosse carregara, infelizmente, não tinha reparado a escrita correta. Muitíssimo obrigado! Fixed!

Comment: Acontece, eu também me confundia bastante no começo.

Answer (score -1):

Entre no Console do seu navegador e vá até a aba de rede (Network), recarregue a página e veja se há algum erro de carregamento.

Se houver, verifique se a chamada (link) da imagem esta correto.

Como o amigo disse acima, é difícil saber apenas com este bloco de código, mas é bastante provável que a chamada da imagem esta referenciando o local errado, talvez pelo simples fato de não ter uma barra antes e o navegador utilizar o caminho dinâmico para chamar a imagem.

Se colocar um / ele partirá da raiz para o caminho da imagem:

```
    <img scr="/img/centro-distribuicao.png">
```

É apenas uma possibilidade, talvez não solucione. Caso não, nos fornece alguma informação adicional por favor.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Infelizmente por descuido havia um erro de sintaxe que eu não havia percebido! Mas obrigado!